# How do I set the materialize swipeable tabs at bottom?

Tags: tabs, materialize

How do I set the **[materialize swipeable tabs](http://materializecss.com/tabs.html)** at bottom?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give the tabs absolute positioning,

```
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

like so: https://jsfiddle.net/8ctz7gpc/

Comment: I am testing your solution on **Swipeable Tabs** and it does not work. Works with **normal tabs**. Because it can be?

Comment: See **Materialize Swipeable Tabs** link, please.

Comment: I have created a test website [link](https://festi.global/base/) and your solution works with **Fixed**, but **Swipeable** has stopped working in **Mobile**.